# MongoDB - javascript query language

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Is there a complete reference for MongoDB's repl? I would like to know all the available JS commands I can use as I would like to port the interface into the browser.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands/ ?

Answer (score 3):

following mongodb.org article has good description on mongodb commands
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/javascript/

Following link has all the javascript commands
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/

Following link has SQL to MongoDB Mapping Chart
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

there is a documentation about mongodb for javascript,

http://api.mongodb.org/js/

there are the commands and more things about that.

docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands

there is a tutorial to how use that

http://www.hacksparrow.com/the-mongodb-tutorial.html